# Wordpress - GD Star Rating - turn off and on for specific posts?

Tags: wordpress, gd

I'm trying to apply GD star rating plugin to 4 specific pages.

I know I can do it in the page editor, but I have about 30 pages so don't want to spend ages going through them all.

Is there a way in the GD settings to default the plugin to not putting the block automatically on every page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Open up your themes directory, find the posts/header/etc php file and insert the block in there. You might need to use `is_post()` or `is_article()` or `category()` functions so they only are displayed in where you want them. Assuming they are all in one category.

Or you can hack the GD plugin. You really have to look at the code to see what it does. Good Luck!

Comment: thanks very much, but this is not what I am asking. I want to alter the settings in the plugin admin not my theme!